# FacesContext#getCurrentInstance() returns null in Filter#doFilter()

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters

Inside a

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
```

I wanted to get the session using

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
```

But I realised that `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` returns `null`. I know that I can get the session using `((HttpServletRequest) req).getSession(false)` instead, but my concrete question is: *why* is the faces context `null` in the `doFilter()` method?

I'm using MyFaces 1.1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`FacesContext` as an object is tied directly to the JSF request processing lifecycle and as a result is only available *during* a standard JSF (user-driven) request-response process. The actual object itself is stored in a thread that runs during the processing of a JSF request, vis-a-vis a ManagedBean.

But. BalusC has outlined some steps to get your hands on the object outside of the processing lifecycle [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html#AccessingTheFacesContextInsideHttpServletOrFilter). :)