# Why Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, google-maps-api-3

I want to send data from javascript to managedbean via servlet but the problem is that first time code works fine but when i returned to the original jsp page containing javascript code and again click on submit button to move to servlet the values are shown in console but an error occur and redirection to jsp page fails.

JSP page containing javascript:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=drawing,geometry"></script>
        <style>
            html, body
            {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                height: 100%;
            }
            .map{height:40%;}
        </style>
        <script>
       function initialize()
            {
                function getURLParameter(name) {
                    return decodeURI(
                            (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search) || [, null])[1]
                            );
                }
                alert("my function in jason");
                var jsonString = getURLParameter("str");
//                var strr = '{mapBean.str1}';
                alert(jsonString);
                var goo = google.maps,
                        map_in = new goo.Map(document.getElementById('map_in'),
                                {zoom: 12,
                                    center: new goo.LatLng(32.344, 51.048)
                                }),
                        shapes = [],
                        selected_shape = null,
                        drawman = new goo.drawing.DrawingManager({map: map_in}),
                        byId = function(s) {
                            return document.getElementById(s)
                        },
                        clearSelection = function() {
                            if (selected_shape) {
                                selected_shape.set((selected_shape.type
                                        ===
                                        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER
                                        ) ? 'draggable' : 'editable', false);
                                selected_shape = null;
                            }
                        },

                goo.event.addListener(drawman, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
                    var shape = e.overlay;
                    shape.type = e.type;
                    goo.event.addListener(shape, 'click', function() {
                        setSelection(this);
                    });
                    setSelection(shape);
                    shapes.push(shape);
                });

                goo.event.addListener(map_in, 'click', clearSelection);
                goo.event.addDomListener(byId('clear_shapes'), 'click', clearShapes);            
                goo.event.addDomListener(byId('save_raw'), 'click', function() {
                    var data = IO.IN(shapes, false);
                    byId('data').value = JSON.stringify(data);
                    if (this.shapes) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < this.shapes.length; ++i) {
                            this.shapes[i].setMap(null);
                        }
                    }
                    for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; ++i) {
                        shapes[i].setMap(null);
                    }
                    shapes = [];
                    alert("clear");

                });
                goo.event.addDomListener(byId('restore'), 'click', function() {

                    if (this.shapes) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < this.shapes.length; ++i) {
                            this.shapes[i].setMap(null);
                        }
                    }
                    //  alert(jsonString);

                    this.shapes = IO.OUT(JSON.parse(byId('data').value), map_in);
                });

            }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br/>
        <div class="map" id="map_in"></div>
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <form method="get" action="GeofencingServlet">
                <input id="clear_shapes" value="clear shapes"    type="button"  />
                <!--<input id="save_encoded" value="save encoded(IO.IN(shapes,true))"    type="button" />-->
                <input id="save_raw"     value="save raw(IO.IN(shapes,false))"        type="button" />
                <input id="data"    name="data"     value=""                style="width:100%" readonly/>
                <input type="submit" id="restore"      value="restore(IO.OUT(array,map))"         type="button" />
                <!--<input type="submit" name="save" value="Create Zone!" id="save" />-->
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

GeofencingServlet:

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<p>Zone created successfully.</p>");
        out.println("<a href=\"gefencingJason.jsp\">Click here!</a>to go back to Map");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

        //  String str = request.getParameter("vertices");
        String str = request.getParameter("data");
        System.out.println("str in servlet" + str);
        MapBean mapBean = new MapBean();
        String strret = mapBean.geo(str);
        System.out.println("servlettttt string returned by mapbean" + strret);
        ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        context.redirect(context.getRequestContextPath() + "/gefencingJason.jsp?str=" + strret);
    }
```

MapBean:

```
 public String geo(String str) throws IOException {
 System.out.println("The data in map bean is str" + str);
        str1 = "my string";
        return str;
    }
```

I have following error:

```
WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[GeofencingServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet GeofencingServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at servlet.GeofencingServlet.doGet(GeofencingServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

INFO:   str in servlet[{"type":"RECTANGLE","id":null,"geometry":[[32.33265644167479,50.932273864746094],[32.352090586480486,50.985145568847656]]}]
INFO:   The data in map bean is str[{"type":"RECTANGLE","id":null,"geometry":[[32.33265644167479,50.932273864746094],[32.352090586480486,50.985145568847656]]}]
INFO:   servlettttt string returned by mapbean[{"type":"RECTANGLE","id":null,"geometry":[[32.33265644167479,50.932273864746094],[32.352090586480486,50.985145568847656]]}]
```

Comment: NPE is at line 60, which one is line 60 in your GeofencingServlet

Comment: line 60 :   ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

Comment: Can you debug your code and check if `FacesContext` or `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` is null.

Comment: did you tried printing FacesContext instance and FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()?

Comment: Have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14394992/3898076

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14394992/3898076), FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() returns null.

You may use below code.

```
//ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
//context.redirect(context.getRequestContextPath() + "/gefencingJason.jsp?str=" + strret);
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/gefencingJason.jsp?str=" + strret);
```

or you may refer [this](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html#AccessingTheFacesContextInsideHttpServletOrFilter) article by @BalusC.

Comment: thanks @Naman Gala its worked i have tried and checked that FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() was causing problem.

Comment: And also have a look at the article written by @BalusC

Answer (score 0):

Always remember: *Check your targeted runtimes(server) for your project in your IDE*.

**For eclipse IDE**:

Goto properties of your project and look for `"Targeted Runtimes"` option. Check your desired *runtime environment*.